# Best way to get Session and Release session in HIbernate/SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, session

Consider the below two codes.

```
Session session = null;
query = "update Employee set EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'Jay' where EMPLOYEE_ID = 1";

    try {
        session = getSession();
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(dlquery);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(session != null) {
            releaseSession(session);
        }
    }
```

And....

```
Session session = getSession();
query = "update Employee set EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'Jay' where EMPLOYEE_ID = 1";
    try {
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(dlquery);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(session != null) {
            releaseSession(session);
        }
    }
```

Which among the two is better to use? Or is there a better way? What wrong I might be doing here?

Also should we do a null check before calling releaseSession(session) in finally?

Answer (score 2):

Truly, the best way is to leverage Spring and its JPA/Hibernate support.... You'll never have to deal with it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'd say there wasn't much difference at all in the two, but you should always check if the session is null, just so you don't cause another NullReferenceException.

Unfortunately this is probably the cleanest way to do this in Java, as there is no such thing as the "using" statement as there is in C#, which allows you to dispose the object after the using block has finished executing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a transaction. If tomorrow you change your code to add another update for instance, you won't have to worry about any consistency problem in case something happens while executing an update.  Aside from that, I would suggest using parameters in your query rather than hard-coding the values. This way you could reuse the query.

Answer (score 1):

If `getSession()` throws an Exception for some reason, would not it be problem in second solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below syntax to get and release session.

```
        session = getSession();
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(dlquery);
        query.executeUpdate();
        session.close();
```